# Search in datagrid using value in textbox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagrid

How can I display value in msgbox. In the first column in datagrid is looking value based on textbox and I want display value from second column and the same row in msgbox. Now I have only "Item found"

[Here are columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYQxq.png)

```
Private Sub PictureBox12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox12.Click


        Dim temp As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To List2DataGridView.RowCount - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To List2DataGridView.ColumnCount - 1
                If List2DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString = TextBox2.Text Then
                    MsgBox("Intem found")
                    temp = 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
        If temp = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Item not found")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate `List2DataGridView.Rows` directly via `For Each`, there is no need to use indexing to visit them.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In List2DataGridView.Rows
```

Then, for each row we test its value and when we find the matching row, we display a message incorporating its value. We have access to the value because it is in scope. When we find the matching element we exit the `For Each`

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In List2DataGridView.Rows
    If row.Cells.Item(1).Value = TextBox2.Text Then
        MsgBox("Item is found in row: " & row.Index)
        MsgBox("Value of second column in this row: " & row.Cells.Item(1).Value)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
MsgBox("Item not found")
```

However this is not the most elegant solution and suffers from poor readability. Specifically, use of `Exit For` is somewhat ugly and makes the code harder to grok at a clance.

We can do better by using LINQ.

```
Dim Matches = From row As DataGridViewRow In List2DataGridView.rows
              Let CellValue = row.Cells.Item(1).Value
              Where CellValue = TextBox2.Text
              Select New With {CellValue, row.Index}

Dim Match = Matches.FirstOrDefault()

If Match IsNot Nothing Then
    MsgBox("Item is found in row: " & Match.Index)
    MsgBox("Value of second column in this row: " & Match.CellValue)
End If
```

Comment: Kindly explain when you answer any question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @manu I edited this to explain the code and also provide a more readable version, not sure if it answers the question or not though since I find the question's intent unclear

Answer (score -1):

```
 Private Sub PictureBox12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox12.Click

        Dim barcode As String
        Dim rowindex As String
        Dim found As Boolean = False
        barcode = InputBox("Naskenujte čárový kód ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||")
        If Len(Trim(barcode)) = 0 Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In List2DataGridView.Rows
            If row.Cells.Item("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1").Value = barcode Then
                rowindex = row.Index.ToString()
                found = True
                Dim actie As String = row.Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn2").Value.ToString()
                MsgBox("Čárový kód:  " & barcode & vbNewLine & "Číslo dílu je:  " & actie, , "Vyhledání dílu")

                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not found Then
            MsgBox("Item not found")
        End If
    End Sub
```